# Powershell XAML with a ListBox

Tags: powershell, xaml, listboxitem

This my first Question !
In the following code in Powershell, I can't bind a collection of objects to a listBox.

The listbox remains empty
I create a collection called dgSourceData in which usernames are stored.
The XAML defines the window.
The FormMain window is created and I add DataContext parameters.
Then I create the binding to the ListBox.
Finally, the window is displayed, but the user listbox remains empty.

```
using namespace System.Windows
using namespace System.Windows.Data
using namespace System.Windows.Controls
using namespace System.Windows.Markup
using namespace System.Xml
using namespace System.Collections.ObjectModel


Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework, PresentationCore, WindowsBase

# $Liste = Import-Csv .\usersAD.csv
$liste = "Marie","Michel","Jean","Adam","Paul"

$Out = @()
$dgSourceData = $Liste | ForEach-Object {
   $out += [PSCustomObject]@{
      Name = $_       # .Name
   }
   return $out
}
  
[xml]$xaml = @"
    <Window 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SetTelephone"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="365" Width="837"
        >
    <Grid>
        <Label x:Name="LabelCompte" Content="Compte :" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="122,128,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="123" Height="31" FontSize="18" FontFamily="Arial"/>
        <Label x:Name="LabelTel" Content="Tel :" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="453,128,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="18" Width="80" Height="31"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="BoxTel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="552,128,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="139" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="18" Height="31"/>
        <Button x:Name="BoutonMaj" Content="Maj" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="376,255,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="45" Width="100"/>
        <Button x:Name="BoutonLire" Content="Lire" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="603,255,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="43" Width="106"/>
        <ListBox x:Name="ListBox" Margin="215,127,389,162" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="18"/> 
    </Grid>
</Window> 
"@

$FormMain = [XamlReader]::Load([XmlNodeReader] $xaml)

$FormMain.DataContext =
 @{
   # The collection must *directly* contain the objects to bind, hence the use of .SubObject
   GridDataSource = [ObservableCollection[Object]] $dgSourceData.SubObject
}

# Create a data binding.
$dgBinding = 
  [Binding] @{
    Mode = [BindingMode]::TwoWay
    Path = '[GridDataSource]' # Index into the hashtable stored in $FormMain.DataContext  
  }

$null = 
  [BindingOperations]::SetBinding(
    $FormMain.FindName('ListBox'), # the target grid control
    [DataGrid]::ItemsSourceProperty, # what grid property to bind to 
    $dgBinding # the data binding
  )

# $reader = new-object system.xml.xmlnodereader $xaml
# $Window = [windows.markup.xamlreader]::Load($reader)

 #
 # Gestions 
 # 

 # .......Button Management

 $Maj = $window.findName('BoutonMaj')
 $Lire = $window.findName('BoutonLire')


$null = $FormMain.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Does this article address your concern? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65013633/using-powershell-data-binding-to-create-a-dynamic-listbox